# selenium and tagit component : how to select

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm not a programmer and a total beginner using Selenium IDE 2.8.0.

I'm trying to record a test but I get stuck when it comes to select a value in 1 zone where you can select from 1 to several values, coming from a dropdown list. All in the same zone. Each time I click in this zone the list appears and I select a value. I can add as many values as I need.

The component used by developpers for this zone is called "tagit.

I don't know how to select the value with Selenium. It does not understand the command "select id=ui-id-62" which works in zones which contain a single value coming from a drowdown list.

Hope to be clear enough

Comment: Need more details. Possible to supply a link or example code? If it's like the flick drop down on http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/ then it's not a true drop down.

Comment: Yes it's a Jquery Tag-it like the flick drow down list you sent. 
Developers told me that the "zone" itself is a text field. But the values inserted, have to come from a pre defined list of values from the database we use. Sorry I don't have access to the code.

Comment: you do have access to the "code" by which I meant the HTML source.

Comment: <tr>
 <td>click<td>
 <td>id=zonelabel<td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>pause<td>
 <td>1000<td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click<td>
 <td>id=ui-id_62<td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: I meant the HTML source of the test page... Also, use the formtting options to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

@DMart

```
<tr>
    <td>click<td>
    <td>id=zonelabel<td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause<td>
    <td>1000<td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click<td>
    <td>id=ui-id_62<td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The list item element IDs that make up the list of options presented by the tag-it library are not consistent, but you can solve by using a xpath reference, referencing the nth item in the dropdown.

The first command here is selecting the input area, the second command is selecting the third item from the list of options that tag-it provides.

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=(//input[@type='text'])[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=(//li[@class='ui-menu-item'])[3]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I hope this helps. It was driving me slightly crazy for a while, but this works for me.